# How to display count result of sql count inside a foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql, count

I have a problem displaying the result of a count inside a foreach loop.

This is my code:

```
<?php
$total_pages = ceil($total_rows / $no_of_records_per_page);
$sql="SELECT * from tblclasses LIMIT $offset, $no_of_records_per_page";
$anzahl="SELECT COUNT(*) as Anzahl FROM tblbooking join  tblclasses on tblbooking.ClassID=tblclasses.ID WHERE DatumZeit like '%25.06.2023%'";
$query = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$query2 = $dbh->prepare($anzahl);
$query->execute();
$query2->execute();
$results=$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$results2=$query2->fetch();

$cnt=1;
if($query->rowCount() > 0)
{
    foreach($results as $row)
    {?>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="classes-item-warp">
                <div class="classes-item">
                    <!-- <div class="ci-img">
                        <img src="admin/images/<?php echo $row->Titelbild;?>" alt="">
                    </div> -->
                    <div class="ci-text">
                        <h4><a href="classes-details.php?viewid=<?php echo $row->ID;?>"><?php echo $row->TypeofClasses;?></a></h4>
                    
                        <p>Datum und Uhrzeit:</p>
                        <p><?php echo $row->DatumZeit;?></p>
                        <p>-----------</p>
                        <p><?php echo $results2['Anzahl'];?><p>

                    </div>
                    <div class="ci-bottom">
                        <div class="ci-author">
                            <img src="admin/images/<?php echo $row->ProfilePics;?>" alt="">
                            <div class="author-text">
                                <h6><?php echo $row->Trainer;?></h6>
                                <p>Dauer: <?php echo $row->Dauer;?></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <a href="book-yoga-sesion.php?cid=<?php echo $row->ID;?>" class="site-btn sb-gradient">Buchen</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

And now I want to display the amount of participants which booked a certain date (Column in sql DatumZeit). If I hardcode it like shown above it works, but it displays just the number of bookings of the hardcoded date.
I want to display on each course how often it was booked.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it, maybe for someone who is interested:

The new if statement inside the loop:

```
            <?php

            $courseDate = $row->DatumZeit;
            $participantCount = 0;
            foreach ($results2 as $result) {
                if ($result['DatumZeit'] === $courseDate) {
                    $participantCount = $result['Anzahl'];
                    break;
                }
            }
            echo "<p>$participantCount participants<p>";
            ?>
```

And the changed sql query:

```
$anzahl = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS Anzahl, DatumZeit FROM tblbooking JOIN tblclasses ON tblbooking.ClassID = tblclasses.ID GROUP BY DatumZeit";e here
```